# how to locate Topic headings in tridion

Tags: 2013

I want to translate topic headings in tridion but I don't know from where they are coming. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You could try searching for the text in the topic?

Comment: Anish - how are your _Topic Headings_ put into Tridion in the first place? Are these specific fields in specific schema? Are they specifically tagged in RTF fields +/- across specific schema? Without the information on how your data is available you likely won't get a specific answer to help out.

Answer (score 3):

From either the Content Manager Explorer or Experience Manager you can use two options to see how items are used in the Blueprint or related to other items:

- Blueprint Hierachy (Bluerint Viewer)
- Where Used

Select the item containing that field and then use those commands to see that item's parent and/or localized versions or what it links to and what links to it.

Otherwise, "headings" (there is no explicit concept of "topic headings" in Tridion, those are likely based on your specific content model) often come from Component, Page, or Structure Group metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Structure Group fields and meta data. Mostly Navigation build on Struct so you can find these information there.